# proving that the distance between two cars cannot always be greater than one mile

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

> The question and solution, followed by some questions I have about the solution are shown below.

[image]

[image]
[image]

> My questions:

From my understanding, the first car starts at A and ends at B while the second car starts at B and ends at A and the two cars travel on different roads.

1. The question seems a little ambiguous, so is it correct to assume that the first car travels from A to B while the second car does anything and then the second car travels from B to A and the first anything afterwards?
2. Why can we assume WLOG that the cars travelled on one day from A to B, keeping a distance of at most one mile between them, and on the next day they travelled in opposite directions in the same time interval?
3. What are the precise parametrizations of the road?
4. Why does the first car travel on the same road in the same direction on both days?
5. Can someone elaborate on their explanation of why we can ensure the motion of the first car yields the same parametrization of the road on both days?
6. Why is it that the two cars are in the same position as they were the day before if $f(t) = g(t)$?

> Alternatively, I'd accept a different answer that doesn't necessarily answer all the questions above, but that is (arguably) easier to understand than the answer I provided above.

Comment: The solution works only if the two cars use those two roads *and no others* during the same time period. As written, technically it does not rule out the case where one car drives from A to B, then to C, after which the other car drives from D to B, then to A. Also, actual roads in the real world have multiple lanes and the lane you drive in one direction is generally not the same as the lane you drive in the other direction. Effectively that introduces a third path.